# Sending parameter to anonymous function

Tags: jquery

My code looks like this:

```
var x = $(function(){
    $('.lobipanel-basic').lobiPanel({
        "state": "unpinned", 
        "resize": "both",
        "reload": false,
        "unpin": false,
        "editTitle": false
    });
}); 

x();
```

This works just fine. What if I want to send a parameter to function `x()`. Basically I don't want to, for obvious reasons, hardcode the class name `.lobipanel-basic`.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just provide the parameter to the function as you would normally. Also note that what you have is not an IIFE. You're just providing an anonymous function to jQuery's event document.ready handler.

Comment: What are the *"obvious reasons"*? This sounds like an XY problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a function that can initialize a plugin by passing in a selector just do:

```
function initPanel(selector){
    $(selector).lobiPanel({
        "state": "unpinned", 
        "resize": "both",
        "reload": false,
        "unpin": false,
        "editTitle": false
    });
}

$(function(){
    initPanel('.lobipanel-basic');
});
```

Or store options in an object and do something like:

```
var panelOpts = {
    "state": "unpinned", 
    "resize": "both",
    "reload": false,
    "unpin": false,
    "editTitle": false
}; 

$(function(){
    $('.lobipanel-basic').lobiPanel(panelOpts);
});
```

Comment: this works, but i want some callable function taking `'.lobipanel-basic'` as a parameter so that i can call as many instances as possible dynamically

Comment: And isn't that what the function i showed does? You really need to define your use case better

Comment: Note that most properly written plugins will call `each` inside them so all elements with that class would be affected. Otherwise use your own `each` if it is not written for multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @charlietfl i could solve with the following code

```
function showPanel(panelClassName){
var panelOpts = {
    "state": "unpinned", 
    "resize": "both",
    "reload": false,
    "unpin": false,
    "editTitle": false
}; 

$(function(){
    $(panelClassName).lobiPanel(panelOpts);
    });
}

showPanel('.lobipanel-basic');
```

@charlietfl: i wanted to load a panel on click of a button. now i can assign the `showPanel` function on button click.

thanks

Comment: so why write new answer that is duplicate of what i gave you? Proper thing would be accept the answer that helped you get to this

Comment: i have generalized the classname in the answer i have posted. although 80% of the code is urs.

Comment: you don't need `$(function(){` if using this in click handler and `generalized` ... you just changed the variable name which is irrelevant. Just not proper etiquette to post a new answer that is almost 100% from other answer